# React Issue With Conditional Then Map

Tags: reactjs

I have some react code that checks if an array has any elements. If it does, then it should map over the elements and display them. I am able to do the check but the map throws an error, and I do not know why.

Here is the function:

```js
    function MetalOptions() {
      const metals_options = GetsOptions(product,"Metal");
      if (metals_options.length > 0) {
        return(
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1>yes</h1>
            <ul>
            {metals_options.map((option,index) =>
              <li key={index}>{option}</li>
              )}
            </ul>
          </React.Fragment>
          );
      }
    }
```

Here is the entire render function:

```js
render() {
    const { isLoading, productID, product} = this.state;

    function GetsOptions(product,kind) {
      const variant_metals = [];
      product.variants.map((variant) =>
          variant.option_values.map((option) =>
              variant_metals.push({type: option.option_type_name,value: option.presentation})
          )
      );

      const filter_variant_metals = variant_metals.filter(item => item.type === kind);
      const output = [...new Set(filter_variant_metals.map(s => JSON.stringify(s)))].map(s => JSON.parse(s));
      return output;
    }

    function GetsVariantImages(product) {
      const variant_images = [];
      product.variants.map((variant) =>
          variant.images.map((image) =>
              variant_images.push({
                original: image.product_url,
                thumbnail: image.small_url,
                description: image.alt,
                originalAlt: image.alt,
                thumbnailAlt: image.alt
              })
            )
        );
      const output4 = [...new Set(variant_images.map(s => JSON.stringify(s)))].map(s => JSON.parse(s));
      return output4;
    }

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div className="sweet-spinner">
              <BounceLoader
                sizeUnit={"px"}
                size={30}
                color={"#494847"}
                loading={isLoading}
              />
            </div>
    }

    function MetalOptions() {
      const metals_options = GetsOptions(product,"Metal");
      const metals_options_array = Object.values(metals_options);
      if (metals_options.length > 0) {
        return(
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1>yes</h1>
            <ul>
            {metals_options_array.map((option,index) =>
              <li key={index}>{option}</li>
              )}
            </ul>
          </React.Fragment>
          );
      }
    }


    const size_options = GetsOptions(product,"Center Diamond Size");
    const shape_options = GetsOptions(product,"Center Diamond Shape");

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-7">
            {product.master.images.length >= 3?
               <section className="main-image-grid">
                {product.master.images.slice(0,3).map(image => 
                  <img key={image.id} src={image.large_url} alt={image.alt}/>
                )}
              </section>:
              <section className="main-image-grid">
                {product.master.images.slice(0,1).map(image => 
                  <img key={image.id} src={image.large_url} alt={image.alt}/>
                )}
              </section>          
            }
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5 gradient-silver">
              <h1 className="text-center">{product.name}</h1>
              <p className="text-center">Your Price {product.display_price}</p>
              <div className="cta">
                <a href={"sms:+19137258268&body=Hello!%20I%20want%20more%20information%20on%20"+product.name}>Text For More Info!</a> 
                <a href="tel:1-913-696-1003">Call To Take A Look</a>
              </div>      
              <h2>Select Your Options</h2>
              <MetalOptions />
              <p>This comes in various options listed below:</p>
                {GetsOptions(product,"Metal").length > 0 &&
                  <h4>yes</h4>
                }  
                {GetsOptions(product,"Center Diamond Shape").length > 0 &&
                  <h2>
                    You have Center Diamond Shape {GetsOptions(product,"Center Diamond Shape").length} Options.
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                  </h2>
                }
                {GetsOptions(product,"Center Diamond Size").length > 0 &&
                  <h2>
                    You have Center Diamond Size {GetsOptions(product,"Center Diamond Size").length} Options.
                  </h2>
                }                         
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr className="style-two"/>
          <ul className="nav justify-content-center" id="productTab" role="tablist">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active" id="center-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#center" role="tab" aria-controls="center" aria-selected="false">Center Gemstones</a>
            </li>          
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" id="description-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#description" role="tab" aria-controls="description" aria-selected="true">Description</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className={"nav-link " + (product.product_properties.length < 0 && 'disabled')} id="properties-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#properties" role="tab" aria-controls="properties" aria-selected="false">Properties</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div className="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div className="tab-pane fade show active" id="center" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="center-tab">
            <h3 className="h5 text-uppercase text-center">The Center</h3>
            <p class="h6 text-center text-muted"><small>Deciding on a center diamond or gemstone is the <span className="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">important decision.</span> The center diamond holds the sentiment and value. If your piece of jewelry is a play, the mounting is a stage, and the center is the actors and script.</small></p>
            <p class="h6 text-center text-muted"><small>We have helped so many in Kansas City find beautiful diamonds or gemstones in all qualities and price ranges usually complete with a GIA grading report. We would be honored to help you to your perfect one.</small></p>
            <DiamondLinks />
            <GemLinks />
            </div>
            <div className="tab-pane fade" id="description" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="description-tab"><p className="text-center">{product.description}</p></div>
            <div className="tab-pane fade" id="properties" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="properties-tab">
            {product.product_properties.map((property,index) =>
                <p><span className="font-weight-bold">{property.property_name}:</span> {property.value}</p>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>          
        </div>
        <hr className="style-two"/>
        <h2>More Pictures</h2>
        <ImageGallery items={GetsVariantImages(product)} lazyLoad={true} showThumbnails={true} thumbnailPosition={'left'}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's the error

Comment: Here is the error: Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Is `option` an object?

Comment: Possibility - how would I check?

Comment: Try removing the `{}` around the map function

Comment: removing the {} gave me a boundary error

Comment: show us your render function. What's the value of metals_options

Comment: Here is the result of GetsOptions(product,"Metal"):

Comment: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {type: "Metal", value: "Platinum"}
1: {type: "Metal", value: "14 Karat Rose Gold"}
2: {type: "Metal", value: "14 Karat Yellow Gold"}
3: {type: "Metal", value: "14 Karat White Gold"}
4: {type: "Metal", value: "18 Karat White Gold"}
5: {type: "Metal", value: "18 Karat Yellow Gold"}
6: {type: "Metal", value: "18 Karat Rose Gold"}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: It's an array of objects, you have to use option.value not option

Comment: `<li key={index}>{option.value}</li>`

Comment: That worked! Stupid mistake. Thanks for the help!